# Append __all__ of a submodule to main module's __all__ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on adding new features to a module: to make the module neater, I am working in a submodule of it.

The `__init__.py` file of this submodule directly imports a list of classes that are going to be used *at the same level as the main module*: by that I mean that the module is most of the time imported by using `from main_module import *`.

I am trying to keep this simplicity by making sure that the `SubmoduleClass` in my submodule is also available with this start import.

For the moment, I have found this slightly redundant solution (see below) of first star-importing the submodule in my main module's `__init__.py`, then also importing the submodule and extending the main module's `__all__` with the submodule's `__all__`

```
### main_module/submodule/__init__.py

from main_module.submodule.some_file import SubModuleClass

__all__ = ["SubModuleClass"]
```

```
### main_module/init.py

... # A lot of other imports
from main_module.submodule import *
import main_module.submodule as submodule

__all__ = [
     ..., # All main module imports
] + submodule.__all__
```

Is there an alternative, simpler solution that I am missing ?

Comment: I think that your current solution is simple enough. It's clear enough certainly.